# How to get image url in .ascx?

Tags: image, field, sitecore

I have an image field in Sitecore from which I need its url. In code behind I have one item:

```csharp
Item contactSlide = itemHelper.GetItemByPath("/sitecore/content/AMM/Resources/Slides/Slide Contact");
```

In the `.ascx` it looks like this:

```html
<div class="contact-section grid-padding-big" style="background-image: url(img/bg.jpg)">
```

I need to replace `img/bg.jpg` with the url of the image field of the item.

In repeaters I normally have a method in the code behind for this:

```csharp
    public string GetImageUrl(Item item)
    {
        Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField imgField = ((Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField)item.Fields["Bild"]);
        if (imgField.MediaItem != null)
        {
            string mediaUrl = Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(imgField.MediaItem);
            return mediaUrl;
        }
        return "";
    }
```

And in the `.ascx` I call it like this:

```html
<div style="background-image:url(<%# GetImageUrl((Sitecore.Data.Items.Item) Container.DataItem) %>)"></div>
```

This works when using this method while in repeaters. But now I have a single item. How can I pass the item to the method to get its image url? Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Pretty sure you can call just call Page.DataBind() to support the <%# syntax outside a repeater. Doing so will also mean that page editor does not break as per the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use code in a `.ascx` within `<%=` and `%>`, so you could simply do this:

```html
<div style="background-image:url(<%= GetImageUrl(itemHelper.GetItemByPath("/sitecore/content/AMM/Resources/Slides/Slide Contact")) %>)"></div>
```

You can also define a method in your code behind to directly get the url from the item you have already resolved:

```csharp
public string GetBackgroundImageUrl()
{
   Item contactSlide = itemHelper.GetItemByPath("/sitecore/content/AMM/Resources/Slides/Slide Contact");
   return this.GetImageUrl(contactSlide);
}
```

And call this in the `.ascx`:

```html
<div style="background-image:url(<%= GetBackgroundImageUrl() %>)"></div>
```